# Using PHP preg_match to subscript numbers in html markup

Tags: php, regex

In order to write correct molecular formulas, I'm trying to subscript numbers following letters or numbers in-between letters, but not numbers that only precede letters (coefficients). For example, in 4H2O, only the "2" should be subscripted. So far I've arrived at the following solution:

```
$oldFormula = "4H2O"
$newFormula = preg_replace('/([A-Z)])([0-9]+)/', '\1<sub>\2</sub>', $chemical_MF);
```

This works perfectly for the above example, where all the atomic symbols are single letters. In "C6H8Cl2O2", however, all of the numbers are subscripted properly except for the "2" following Cl (chlorine). I'm a novice at regex and need help with this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$oldFormula = "C6H8Cl2O2";
$newFormula = preg_replace('/([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]+)/', '\1<sub>\2</sub>', $oldFormula);
var_dump($newFormula);
```

This works if the 2nd character is *always* lower case. You could simply replace it with:

```
/([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)/
```

This would also match `aA0`.

I changed two things:

1

```
/([A-Z)])([0-9]+)/
//    ^-- this character should not be here, you're matching A-Z and )
```

2 I added `[a-z]?` which means: followed by `a-z` optionally.

Comment: Wow! What a silly mistake. This works perfectly. I forgot the lowercase match. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
$newFormula = preg_replace('/([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]+)/', '\1<sub>\2</sub>', $chemical_MF);
```